# How to use Bootstrap Top navbar and Sidebar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried to use top nav and sidebar in bootstrap 4. but it doesn't go well

I have header.jsp that is used as top nav. 
It's linked with sidebar page using action tag. like this

```
<header>
    <jsp:include page="../subPage/header.jsp"/>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar"> ... </div>
</body>
```

but it doesn't work. [It fell apart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1lkm.gif)

after that, I searched web and adjusted css of sidebar

```
.sidebar {  position: fixed;   }
```

but it doesn't work as well [because of overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQXsT.gif)

Any tips that I can use?

[position:absolute top:50px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNqOO.gif)

[position:fixed top:50px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7BaH.gif)

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
```

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar)
 * Copyright 2013-2017 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#" class="bg-primary">HTML
                </a>
            </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Lecture 1</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
            <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens,
                and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will
                appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
            <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give `.sidebar` `top` property it's value will be your `header` height

```
.sidebar {  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. it doesn't work.. i've add absolute and fixed image.If you don't mind, I'd like you to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @sakaimasato , can you show me a picture that you want. 
or your code ??

Answer (score 0):

Here the code for Navbar and sidebar of bootstrap 4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 hidden-xs-down bg-faded sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reports</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 pt-3">
          <h1>Dashboard</h1>

          <section class="row text-center placeholders">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAJ12AAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <div class="text-muted">Something else</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAADcgwAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAJ12AAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAADcgwAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
          </section>

          <h2>Section title</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,001</td>
                  <td>Lorem</td>
                  <td>ipsum</td>
                  <td>dolor</td>
                  <td>sit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,002</td>
                  <td>amet</td>
                  <td>consectetur</td>
                  <td>adipiscing</td>
                  <td>elit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,003</td>
                  <td>Integer</td>
                  <td>nec</td>
                  <td>odio</td>
                  <td>Praesent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,003</td>
                  <td>libero</td>
                  <td>Sed</td>
                  <td>cursus</td>
                  <td>ante</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,004</td>
                  <td>dapibus</td>
                  <td>diam</td>
                  <td>Sed</td>
                  <td>nisi</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,005</td>
                  <td>Nulla</td>
                  <td>quis</td>
                  <td>sem</td>
                  <td>at</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,006</td>
                  <td>nibh</td>
                  <td>elementum</td>
                  <td>imperdiet</td>
                  <td>Duis</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,007</td>
                  <td>sagittis</td>
                  <td>ipsum</td>
                  <td>Praesent</td>
                  <td>mauris</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,008</td>
                  <td>Fusce</td>
                  <td>nec</td>
                  <td>tellus</td>
                  <td>sed</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,009</td>
                  <td>augue</td>
                  <td>semper</td>
                  <td>porta</td>
                  <td>Mauris</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,010</td>
                  <td>massa</td>
                  <td>Vestibulum</td>
                  <td>lacinia</td>
                  <td>arcu</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,011</td>
                  <td>eget</td>
                  <td>nulla</td>
                  <td>Class</td>
                  <td>aptent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,012</td>
                  <td>taciti</td>
                  <td>sociosqu</td>
                  <td>ad</td>
                  <td>litora</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,013</td>
                  <td>torquent</td>
                  <td>per</td>
                  <td>conubia</td>
                  <td>nostra</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,014</td>
                  <td>per</td>
                  <td>inceptos</td>
                  <td>himenaeos</td>
                  <td>Curabitur</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,015</td>
                  <td>sodales</td>
                  <td>ligula</td>
                  <td>in</td>
                  <td>libero</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This could maybe help, but is there any reason why you are using a so old version of Bootstrap? The current version is 4.0.0 (stable)!

Comment: Strangely, even with your example snippet, your content came after sidebar (not on its side) and navbar is covering part of side bar and its style doesn't seem correct. I guess that is all because you forget to include the mystery dashboard.css file in here